# Sample path boundedness of Gaussian Processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, stochastic-calculus

Consider a Gaussian Process $GP(0,k(x,x'))$ with zero mean and bounded, continues covariance function $k(x,x')<c,\quad \forall x,x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Are the sample paths of this process (almost surly) bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$? If yes, why? If not, what additional assumption is needed?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think there's an argument by arguing that ${\mathbb R}^n$ is totally bounded in the standard deviation metric $d(x,x')=\sqrt{\mathrm{var}[Y_x-Y_{x'}]}$, but I haven't found the details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you provide some more details about it?